# Android get location every X number of minutes

Tags: android, service, gps, location, alarm

I am trying to create an app that will collect 10 number of location changes every 10 minutes. What I am currently trying to do is have an alarm manager that will start a service every 10 minutes. The service will have a LocationManager that will get start a LocationListener and get location updates 10 times before the service stops itself. However, I am not sure why I am not getting any location updates. Can anyone help point out any mistakes I have?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static ArrayList <Location> mLocationList;
public static int counter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Will add in the bits for the LocationList after fixing the location problem
    mLocationList = new ArrayList<Location>();
    counter = 0;

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TrackingService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent,0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 10, pintent);
    }   
}
```

and here is what I have for my Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mlocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            0, 0, this);

    return START_STICKY;
}

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    // Unregistering listeners
        mlocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        MainActivity.counter=0;
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location == null) {
        return;
    }

    else {

            MainActivity.mLocationList.add(location);
            MainActivity.counter++;
            double lat=location.getLatitude();
            double lng=location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location" + lat + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (MainActivity.counter == 9){
        this.stopSelf();
    }       
}
```

Comment: can I ask why you want locations in this manner? To maybe offer you a better option

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how it would work.